# Flyway does not ignore out of order migration scripts, with outOfOrder=false

Tags: validation, flyway

I am not using outOfOrder.
I would like to be able to add a migration script, that would not be the latest, (e.g. to bugfix an existing script, without changing that script).

I would like the new script to be run, as part of the normal ordering, on databases that haven't been migrated yet.
Any databases that are up to date (e.g. manually repaired) should ignore the new script.

From the documentation:

> OutOfOrder - Allows migrations to be run "out of order". If you
>   already have versions 1 and 3 applied, and now a version 2 is found,
>   it will be applied too instead of being ignored.

This suggests that the new script will be ignored, but I get the error:

> ERROR: Validate failed: Detected resolved migration not applied to database

Will the new script only be ignored if the db baseline is ahead of it?
Is this the expected behaviour?

If so, I guess my solution here is either to:

- Use outOfOrder, and complicate all my scripts to be idempotent.
- Baseline my db after every migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pull request for this that will be merged in time for Flyway 5.1.0: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/1866

Until then you also have the option to disable validation by setting `validateOnMigrate` to `false`.

Comment: So v5 will have a new flag: ignoreIgnoredMigrations.  Until then I'll have to turn off validation.  Thanks